# How can I prevent an applescript from opening .webloc files in a new browser window?

Tags: drag-and-drop, applescript

When double-clicked, this small applescript reads the URL from a .webloc file. But when the same .webloc file is dropped on the script, the according website opens in the default browser *and the script won't execute*. How can I prevent this behavior, and read the URL as intended?

```
on run
    open {choose file with prompt "Choose a file:" without invisibles}
end run

on open the_files
    repeat with i from 1 to (count the_files)
        if type identifier of (info for the_files) is "com.apple.web-internet-location" then
            # "read file" can only access the data fork; the URL is stored inside the resource fork
            tell application "Finder" to set weblocURL to the location of (the_files as alias)
            set the clipboard to weblocURL
        else
            set the clipboard to "bummer"
        end if
    end repeat
end open
```

**this script works:**

```
on run
    open {choose file with prompt "Choose a file:" without invisibles}
end run

on open location this_URL
    set the clipboard to this_URL
end open location

on open the_files
    repeat with i from 1 to (count the_files)
        try
            if type identifier of (info for (item i of the_files)) is "com.apple.web-internet-location" then
                # "read file" can only access the data fork; the URL is stored inside the resource fork
                tell application "Finder" to set weblocURL to the location of (item i of the_files)
                set the clipboard to weblocURL
            else
                set the clipboard to "bummer"
            end if
        end try
    end repeat
end open
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess... I suspect that this type of file sends out an "open location" system wide notification and Safari responds to that notification. So I would suggest you look into modifying your script to respond to "open location". A quick google search turned up [this instruction](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/linktrigger/) which should give you some idea of what you need to change.

Also you have some errors in your code. Inside your repeat loop, any time you use "the_files" you need to replace that with "(item i of the_files)". The reason is that "the_files" is a list of files thus you have a repeat loop to act on each item in that list. So you must act on item i inside the repeat loop to get the actual file out of the list.

Also in your "tell application Finder" line you should remove "as alias". Item i of the_files is already an alias thus you do not need to coerce it to an alias.

Good luck.

Comment: `open location` was indeed the key. thanks for pointing out the other flaws too. cheers!

Comment: Is there a way to get the filepath of the webloc that was dropped onto the app? I don't know how to do this inside the `on open location` …

Comment: I can't see a way either from "open location" because you just get the URLs, so you just have to play with it. It may be that the "on open" handler is also called or some other handler where you might get a reference to the files dropped. If you find one then of course the Finder can give you the paths to the alias files.